# Beautiful Soup 4 HTML parsing

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to extract coefficient table for soccer from 'http://www.flashscore.com/'. As you look source code of page, you can see that table is inside a div with id="fs". But BeautifulSoup returns none when I search for that div. I wrote script as below. What is wrong here?

```
Code
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.flashscore.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
print(soup.find(id="fs"))
```

Comment: `table` is coming from `post` request, you cannot extract it from `get` request.

Comment: So you say that it is impossible to extract these coefficients from this website?

Comment: when did I said this is impossible ?

Comment: I'm just asking...

Comment: I didn't find any div with id='fs'.Anyone tell where is that div with id='fs'?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) because data(div with class fs) is loaded with ajax.When `request.get('http://www.flashscore.com/')` is used only `'http://www.flashscore.com/'` url is requested.No other ajax request are called that are associated with it.
Refer the code below that use selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.flashscore.com/")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "fs"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: ERROR: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Comment: @ElginCahangirov you have to install geckodriver Check this http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#drivers

Comment: Thank you for help! Are you sure that it is not possible to do this with requests module?

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't find any dive id with 'fs' on flashscore.com

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("http://www.flashscore.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
print(soup.find('div',id='fsbody'))
```

soup.find() gives first occurence of id
if you want to find all u can make use of find_all() function

Comment: I tried this. Soup finds div with id 'fsbody', but can't find div with id 'fs'. That is the problem. Look at the inside of div with id 'fsbody', 'fs' is there.

Comment: i couldn't find any div with id **fs**